# Is curl enabled by default with any PHP install?

Tags: php, curl

Is curl extension enabled by default with any PHP install? If yes, then starting from what version of PHP?

Comment: This question is way to broad: What is "any PHP install"? On linux distributions you normally have to separately install a "php-curl" package.

Comment: Is the extension enabled by default: usually no. Is the extension *included*: usually yes. Is this entirely dependent on who package the PHP binary: yes.

Answer (score 0):

You could always check with the trusty phpinfo function. Just remember to delete it afterward. Sorry if this isn't within the scope of your question.

```
<?php
    phpinfo();
?>
```